# Weird behavior using MATCH () AGAINST () with PDO (syntax error)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, full-text-search, lumen

I am working on a query which uses MATCH () AGAINST () on a FULLTEXT index.

What's weird is that the query does not work in PHP's PDO but ***works with HeidiSQL and even MySQL console (mysql -u [...])***.

This is the query I am working on:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `announcements`
WHERE MATCH (`name`, `email`, `trademark`, `model`, `phone`, `city`) AGAINST ('+Ravenna*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This is PDO's error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

`'?) against ('?' in boolean mode))'` at line 1

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS AGGREGATE
FROM `announcements`
WHERE `archived_at` IS NULL
  AND (MATCH (`name`, `email`,  `trademark`, `model`, `phone`, `city`) against ('+Ravenna*' IN boolean MODE))
```

**EDIT:**

This is the function that causes the error:

```php
[...]

$this->customQueries[] = function ($query) use ($words) {

    $columnsToSearch = array_map(function ($key) {
        return "`{$key}`";
    }, [
        'name', 'email', 'trademark', 'model', 'phone', 'city'
    ]);

    $matchColumns = implode(', ', $columnsToSearch);
    $againstWords = value(function () use ($words) {
        $string = "";

        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $string .= "+{$word}* ";
        }

        $string = trim($string);

        return $string;
    });

    // This is specifically the function that causes the error.
    $query->whereNested(function ($q) use ($matchColumns, $againstWords) {
        $q->whereRaw("match (?) against ('?' in boolean mode)", [$matchColumns, $againstWords]);
    });
};
```

I can't understand why it does not work on PDO only.

I have already searched on StackOverflow, all single quotes have been checked already.

Comment: Could you add the relevant PDO code?

Comment: I do not use PDO directly, it's abstracted by Illuminate. @JoachimIsaksson Added some code.

Comment: Is it any different when you remove the backticks? (they are only really necessary for when your column names are reserved words). Anyway, I think illuminate is to blame here. They are evidently turning this into a prepared statement and producing the invalid syntax.

Comment: I tried without backticks as well, same result.

Comment: Funny thing, if I ```\DB::select()``` the query, it gives me the expected output that is the query result.

Comment: If this were PDO, then the match `?` would be getting a single string, not a  list of columns as your working example suggests you want. Similar would go for your `against` part, which may also be failing in part as you've put the `?` inside quotes.

Comment: @JonStirling ```implode(', ', $columnsToSearch)``` makes it a string if you did not notice.

Comment: @GiamPy I noticed, that's part of the point.

Comment: @JonStirling Oh. Are you trying to say that PDO attempts as well to add quotes (since it's a string attempting to get binded) and the result would be double "single quotes" around the string? If so, I don't think that's the case since ```var_dump```'ing the query does not show it.

Comment: Afaik, one does not simply `var_dump` a PDO statement to SQL. So what does your dump show? Also prepared statements aren't as simple as "This question mark gets inline replaced with my value".

Comment: Now that I see the PHP code added to the question, it brings a totally different light on the subject.

Comment: @JonStirling I am sorry. I meant to say that I ```var_dump```'ed the ```toSql()``` of Illuminate that shows me the raw SQL query (without the bindings). Then I just use ```getBindings()``` and replace the values to see the final result. Here's the result: https://gist.github.com/GiampaoloFalqui/5d40ea880de4e80d719a

Comment: @GiamPy I can't help any further I'm afraid. I don't know anything about illuminate, but that appears to be where the problem appears to be coming from.

Comment: Though another thing to consider is that it look like your query's parameters aren't even being replaced anyway since you can see the `?` in the syntax error.

Comment: Isn't it normal to have the error suggestion with ```?``` instead of the query parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot insert a comma-separated string of column names as an argument to a prepared statement. Instead you should just inject them in your SQL statement and not pass them as parameter.

Secondly, you should not wrap placeholders (`?`) with quotes, ever.

So try this modification of your code:

```
$query->whereNested(function ($q) use ($matchColumns, $againstWords) {
    $q->whereRaw("match ($matchColumns) against (? in boolean mode)", [$againstWords]);
 });
```

You might think it bad to inject `$matchColumns` in the SQL string like that, but since you have complete control over that value, there is no risk (of SQL injection).

Comment: It seems like this fixes the issue, so I thank you for that since I have been smashing my head against this for like an entire hour (or more)! However I wonder why I cannot use a comma-separated string as an argument to a prepared statement, could you enligthen me?

Comment: Prepared statements are compiled by the SQL engine. This is only possible if the SQL is complete in terms of tables and columns. Only literal values can be left unknown during the compilation of the statement. See for example this comment in the PHP docs: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304

Comment: Thank you, you saved my life.